# Simulating an XSS attack in a VS2012 MVC4 application

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC 4 application in which i am trying to simulate an XSS attach. I just have a button and text box which will just output the value entered in the text box as below. When i enter `<script>alert('xss')</script>` in the text box automatically an exception is showing stating dangerous value was detected from the client. How can I prevent this atleast for learning purposes
Now the exception does not come after following Furqan's advice. However I would expect the alert message box to appear but it does not and instead the script tag appears as a string.

Can somebody explain why it is this way?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<form method="post" action="/home/index">
<input type ="text" id="text" name="search" value="@ViewBag.Message"/>
<input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

These are my controller actions.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string search)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = search;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: use `[AllowHtml]` attribute on the index method for HTTPPost Request.

Comment: [AllowHtml] is valid only for properties

Comment: sorry forgot the fact, use `[ValidateInput(false)]` on controller action.

Comment: For further reading: [Request Validation in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx)

Comment: Don't forget `@Html.Raw` in the View.

Comment: @Furqan: Thanks that worked but i am still not able to simulate the attack. I have updated my question.

Comment: @ckv that's because MVC4 automatically encode the printed responses to prevent such attacks, one way to simulate it,is using `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)`  to print the search string.

Comment: If you could add it as answers i could upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use both `[ValidateInput(false)]` on Action and `@Html.Raw` in the View:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index(string search)
{
    ViewBag.Message = search;
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<h2>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has a great article on preventing Cross Site Scripting:[How To: Prevent Cross-Site Scripting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx).

You may also like to try some security tools such as [Netsparker](https://www.mavitunasecurity.com/communityedition/) that will test for an array of common, and less common, attack vectors.